# Adding camera icon to the action bar in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

In menu_main.xml,

```
<item
android:id="@+id/camera" 
android:title="camera"
android:icon="@drawable/cam"
android:showAsAction="always" />
```

I can see camera option on my menu(hardware) button click but i can't see icon in action bar.
Do I need to change any action bar settings?

Comment: "I can see camera on my left click but i can't see icon in action bar" - Confusing

Answer (score 3):

Actionbar is now deprecated use toolbar instead

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/bookmark"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="right" >

    <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/bookmarkIv"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_star_uncheck" />
</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

try using a android support library themes like appcompact if you are trying to use this in lower version phones

Answer (score 0):

You can try below in menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/camera"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="camera"
        android:icon="@drawable/cam"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Use app:showAsAction="always" instead of android:showAsAction="always". And remember add xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" in menu. Hope help you.